# What are these bulbs and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: identification

I've recently been removing weeds from a border, and found some bulbs growing throughtout. I remember seeing them last year too (I believe they grow as something grass like but not sure if they flower). I also remember that previously when digging them up they get incredibly dense in the soil, to the point where I had to sheer through them with a spade to remove them last time.

At the moment they're in dribs and drabs, but I don't really want them coming back. Does anyone know what they are exactly and how I can rid myself of them?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They could be Crocosmia masoniorum, commonly known as Montbretia - has sword like leaves, smaller bulbs produce narrower, shorter leaves These look as if they're in tiers or stacks, that is, in a vertical row, one above the other, and that's typical of Crocosmia. There's only one way to rid yourself of them - dig them all up. That might mean waiting for shoots to arrive, and digging down and removing the bulb as soon as you've noticed the growth, unless you want to systematically dig the whole garden and pick through each spadeful as you go.

Comment: If systematically digging the whole garden, use a screen - it's much faster than picking through.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on it and let at least 1 flower, and mark this as the answer if you're correct. The difficulty in digging them is the sheer number and the depth they go to. Unfortunately they growing either side of a fence and the neighbour doesn't mind them so I'll likely never remove them all.

Comment: Yes, their vertical formation of bulbs makes them quite deep if they've been there for some years...